# How do I restrict pipeline triggering

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, pipeline

I am making some changes in my project code and posting it to GitHub. This causes my Azure Pipeline to be triggered every time. How can I restrict pipeline triggering. I'm using Azure DevOps.

Answer (score 1):

You need to disable the [ci trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/github?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#ci-triggers) from the pipeline:

```
# A pipeline with no CI trigger
trigger: none
```

Answer (score 1):

In Azure pipeline , we can disable continuous Integration option as in the attached image reference . This will disable  CI trigger  [image: Azure Disable CI]